# convert unix epoch time to human readable time

Tags: unix, time, epoch

First I have an Unix epoch time  1270787111.

Then based on this website:
http://untangible.com/2009/01/covert-unix-epoch-dates-in-microsoft-excel-including-timezone-examples.html,
I convert the number to be 40276.9758217592.
Then I put the value into an Excel cell and convert it into "Date" format  to be : 4/8/10 23:25
I do not know how this happens. How can the value 40926 be converted into 2010(year)04(month)08(day)? Is there any other programming way to convert an Unix epoch time into a human readable format time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the GNU coreutils `date` command, you can do this:

```
$ date -d @1270787111
Thu Apr  8 21:25:11 PDT 2010
```

If you'd rather do it in C, use `localtime()` or `gmtime()` to convert the `time_t` value 1270787111 to a `struct tm`, then use `asctime()` to convert that to a human-readable string. `ctime(t)` is equivalent to `asctime(localtime(t))`. This assumes that your C library represents `time_t` values as seconds since the Unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00); POSIX guarantees this, but C does not.

`strftime()` takes a `struct tm` and converts it to a human-readable string, letting you control the format, rather than using the default `"Thu Apr  8 21:25:11 2010\n"` format imposed by `ctime()` and `asctime()` (yes, the default format includes a trailing newline).

Be sure to read the documentation for these functions. They require a lot of pointer manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

My personal favorite is

```
perl -E 'say scalar gmtime 1270787111'
```

Answer (score 1):

Excel starts dates from January 0, 1900 (yes, January 0). From this [link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm).

> The integer portion of the number, ddddd, represents the number of days since 1900-Jan-0

The date you end up with 40,276 days after 1/0/1900.

There are usually built-in functions in many programming languages (C/C++, Perl, PHP, etc.) for handling UNIX epoch timestamps. It really just depends on what language you're using as to what methods/functions you would call. Here's a link that shows some [examples in C](http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/functions-c.php).